# Can't compress bitmap android studio

Tags: java, android

In my app I have a fragment which opens the device camera and allows the users to take photos and store them in a directory inside the gallery. This is the method that I use to create the dir and save the taken image:

```
    private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, String image_name) {

        final String appDirectoryName = "/Feel/";
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + appDirectoryName;
        File myDir = new File(root);
        myDir.mkdirs();
        String fname = "Image-" + image_name + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        Log.i("LOAD", root + fname);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except `finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);`. When it comes to this line it skips the process... The directory is not created too... What is causing this problem?

This is my `CameraFragment`, where I retrieve the photo that was shot:

```
 final Button btnShoot = viewCamera.findViewById(R.id.btnShoot);
    imgUltimaFoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btnShoot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cmrView.addCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] picture) {
                    super.onPictureTaken(picture);
                    CameraUtils.decodeBitmap(picture, new CameraUtils.BitmapCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                            imgUltimaFoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            imgUltimaFoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            saveImage(bitmap,"imagem1");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            cmrView.capturePicture();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you creating file and than deleting it: `if (file.exists()) file.delete();`?

Comment: @Yupi Actually, I've thought of that but I just copied away this code so I thought that would be important. Still, I've commented that line and the `finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);` is still not working.

Comment: Do you get any error? Did you check in `LogCat`? Is some `exception` happening, app shouldn't crash because of `try catch` so check `Logcat`

Comment: @Yupi Hm.. it has something to do with the directory... But what it may be?
https://pastebin.com/tCWtej9D

Comment: Your image path from gallery is `null` so no image is `compressed`.

Comment: Oh, I thought that `compress` would save the bitmap in the path that I chose `/Feel/`

Comment: @Yupi How can I solve this?

Comment: It will save but first of all your `bitmap` you want to save must exists and `exception` says it doesn't. No path of bitmap is provided so nothing is saved. In my opinion the best is to load all images from gallery in `RecyclerView` and when user picks one provide path of image. But you are using `onActivityResult` am I right?

Comment: @Yupi please, see my updated question. There is where I retrieve the bitmap

Comment: Are you using some external library for image capture?

Comment: @Yupi Yeah I've implemented this library `implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:1.5.1'`

Comment: Than there could be an issue with the library check they GitHub page.

Comment: @Yupi I'm afraid it isn't an issue. When I debug tho, I click the `finalBitmap` and it shows my the picture I took...

Comment: Okay try by adding this line: `if (!file.exists()) { file.createNewFile();}`

Comment: @Yupi The `createNewFile` creates an exception. It stays underlined red. Idk if this has something to do with it but, when I take a photo using the emulators camera, the photo doesn't appear in the gallery. It does only appear in "Google Photos"... I've tried to scan sd using dev tools but it crashes my emulator

Comment: @Yupi I tried to surround `createNewFile` with a Try Catch but still got no success saving the bitmap